# All the data annotations (or attributes) availabe in Asp.net M-V-C

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any way to look at all the data annotations or attributes available in Asp.net MVC?
i.e. for validation we have "Required", "StringLength" etc, for Action verbs, "HttpPost", "HttpGet" etc, similarly "Bind", "MetadataType" etc.

I am kind of new to Asp.net MVC and MVC is loaded with attributes for different purposes and I don't know if there is an attribute available to do something or even whether to use an attribute to get something done. Is there any documentation of these necessary/helper/nice-to-use attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data annotations, check out [this blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/07/25/notes-on-templates-and-data-annotations-in-mvc-2.aspx).

For other filters (action filters, authorize filters, etc) I'm not aware of a list anywhere, but according to [this article on ASP.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) they implement one of four interfaces:

1. Authorization filters – Implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` attribute.
2. Action filters – Implements the `IActionFilter` attribute.
3. Result filters – Implements the `IResultFilter` attribute.
4. Exception filters – Implements the `IExceptionFilter` attribute.

The ASP.NET MVC source is available on [CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC), so you could search it for classes that implement one of those 4 interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the classes in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `System.Web.Mvc` in Visual Studio's Object Browser.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the MS documentation is really difficult to find!  I came across this post, then ... by chance ... a Jon Galloway video directed me to the following documentation:

[*System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

This post is 4yrs old, but next time I search I'll find the link here!